# How to inject a fake value while testing a contract?

Tags: truffle, test

I'm used to Java mocks, where I could access and modify private values. As we are on our local machine and own ethereum node, we may do the same.

My problem is I want to modify a required address. Only my Oracle is authorized to call a function, and I would like my test to do it so.

```
contract CodeFanSites {
    address  private constant _Oracle = 0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732;

    function addSite(address payable user, string memory domain) external {
        require(msg.sender == _Oracle);
         // ....
    }
}
```

And my tests, using truffle :

```js
contract("CodeFanSites", (accounts) => {
  let [nik, oracle] = accounts;

  it("should be able to add a new domain site", async () => {
    const contract = await CodeFanSites.new();
    console.log({balance: sites, accounts, nik});

    // I need before here to modify the _Oracle private address in the contract
    const result = await contract.addSite(oracle,  "site.com");
    // ....
})
```

How can I change the `_Oracle` private address in the contract before calling the `addSite()` function in the test ?

Note that `_Oracle` don't have to be constant, it may just be private. I don't want anybody to be able to change this value, except while testing.

Comment: you cannot. it is a constant. why you don't give the address as a parameter when you deploy the CodeFanSites Contract? then it will be more flexible

Comment: Because I don't want anybody to be able to change my Oracle adress. It would break my system

Comment: It don't have to be constant though. Private is enough.

Comment: You may want to try something like Smock https://github.com/defi-wonderland/smock.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I think I will stay with truffle for a while, but I will surely move quickly to HardHat with such features.

Comment: The solution I have now is to create a mock folder with copy of the contract, adding some setter functions that I will delete in the prod contract

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is you can't so have to design contracts with a testing plan in mind.

In my opinion, the root of the problem is the hard-coded oracle address. This could be abstract, allowing oracle mocks during testing. Consider:

```
contract CodeFanSites {

  address public immutable _oracle;

  constructor(address oracle) {
    _oracle = oracle;
  }

  function addSite(address payable user, string memory domain) external {
    require(msg.sender == _oracle);
    // ....
  }
}
```

Summary of changes.

1. `_oracle` - style
2. `public` - discoverable state
3. `immutable` - same effect as `constant` but more flexible at deployment time
4. `constructor()` - set the value

You can run tests on local chains or forks of networks, create many accounts and even work with free money and mocks but you cannot force a contract to do something it wasn't coded to do. There is no way to override that hard-coded address or change the logic in the function temporarily.

The proposed method gives the same efficiency as a `constant` and the same immutability as well as a way to confirm correct deployment using the address that it *must be* on the mainnet. You could even consider embedding comments to document your intent - "correct" oracle addresses on different testnets and mainnet.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using "immutable" makes the contract more robust against unintentionally overriding the _oracle address.

Answer (score 1):

You need some functions and keep the owner (contract creator) in private variable.
`_owner` should be set in constructor and a modifier will check `setOracle` function to be called only by the owner.

```
contract CodeFanSites {
    address private _owner;
    address private _Oracle = 0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == _owner, "not authorized");
        _;
    }

    constructor () {
        _owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function setOracle(address oracle) public onlyOwner returns (bool)            
    {
        _Oracle = oracle;
        return true;
    }

    function addSite(address payable user, string memory domain) external {
        require(msg.sender == _Oracle);
         // ....
    }
}
```

then you can set oracle before `addSite` function

```
const result = await contract.setOracle(oracle);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best approach to test the exact same smart contract that will be deployed in production is to use a derivate smart contract for testing and use the `internal` modifier instead of the `private` one.

```
contract CodeFanSites {
    address internal _Oracle = 0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732;
}

contract CodeFanSitesTest is CodeFanSites {

    function init(address _testOracle) public {
        _Oracle = _testOracle;
    }

    function getInternalOracleAddress() public view returns (address) {
        return _Oracle;
    }

}
```

This way, you can test `CodeFanSitesTest` as it is `CodeFanSites`, without worrying to modify `CodeFanSites` before deploying in production: indeed, `private` and `internal` modifiers work exactly the same if there's no derivate contract.

Fewer modifications before deployment mean fewer risks in general.

Answer (score 0):

Note : The option from Rob at constructor time is also very good, probably safer (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/118397/87100)

Finally I did something that [PancakeBunny](https://github.com/PancakeBunny-finance/Bunny/blob/main/contracts/bunny/BunnyChef.sol#L137) and probably others are doing :

```
function addVault(address vault, address token, uint allocPoint) public onlyOwner {
        require(vaults[vault].token == address(0), "BunnyChef: vault is already set");
        ...
}
```

So I don't need anymore mocks for this case, but I keep an eye on [Smock](https://github.com/defi-wonderland/smock) lib

On my code, I added a setter for the owner and Oracle:

```
contract CodeFanSites {
     
   // Initialized to 0
    address OWNER;
    address ORACLE;

    /**
     * Can set owner only once, at deployment
     */
    function setOwner(address owner) public {
        require(OWNER == address(0), "Owner already set");
        OWNER = owner;
    }

    function setOracle(address oracle) public {
        require(msg.sender == OWNER);
        ORACLE = oracle;
    }
}
```

Then I added the values at deploy time, here using hardhat rather than truffle

```
async function main() {
  run('compile');
  const CodeFanDomains = await ethers.getContractFactory('CodeFanDomains');
  const codeFan = await CodeFanDomains.deploy();
  console.log('codeFan deployed to:', codeFan.address);
  const [owner, oracle, johnDoe] = (await ethers.getSigners()).map(u=>u.address)

  const instance = await CodeFanDomains.attach(codeFan.address);
  await instance.setOwner(owner);
  await instance.setOracle(oracle);
  console.log("Deployed ok")
}
```